# Template files not loading

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I know this a newbie question but I can't get the template files to load on a new theme I am working on. I have cleared the cache/theme registry... many times but nothing. I did speed through the process so I think I left something out. Any thought as to what I may be missing. I have run many tests but get no reponse.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you add some code so that we may have a better idea of where you might be going wrong?

Comment: I just started over and it seems to be working now. I didn't have the template.php file and theme-settings.php file setup correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete cache. Devel is a very good modul for this. You can add block with nice button "clear cache". Very useful for themers!

Comment: is that with devel node access? how do I do this. I do have devel installed and running

Comment: Go to admin -> Blocks and add Devel block to the some area. Don't forget to switch on it (2th or 3th link in developer area in admin -> modules)

Comment: ok I enabled devel no access and devel node access by user to the footer but am not getting anything on the page.?

Comment: Could it be that the path is not set correctly to find the template file? I am using the zen staterkitso I figured everything would be linked already.

Comment: There are two types of themes: administration theme (`/admin/settings/adminand`) and general site theme. So this means you can have different themes for your admin pages and another one for the normal pages. Each theme has different areas so adding a block to the footer doesn't necessarily mean you'll see the block there. Read the instructions in the Zen starter-kit, they're quite comprehensive. And this is (just like the name says) a starter kit. Not a full theme like Garland for example.